# Which is better to create a object using data migration or by using code?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating an object like this through code:

```
if not Abc.objects.filter(name='xyz').exists():
    Abc.objects.create(username='xyz')
```

but I can create it through data migration also:

```
def create_myobj(apps, schema_editor):
    do stuff

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
   dependencies = [ ('myapp', 'your last migration'), ]
   operations = [ migrations.RunPython(create_myobj) ]
```

So which is a better choice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-for-models

Comment: depends on your needs and the context...

Comment: You need additional checks for the first case, because there might be several threads or even applications trying to create `Abc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data Migration` should be better according to your scenario

Why Data Migration: If you will create an object through code so in this situation every time when you use your function then Django will check `Abc exist or not`,
means you are losing your computational power and time also.

> but another way when you will user Data Migration it will run once
>   while database migrates and it will make a database object entry

.